# In few cases, Can we restrict the question before getting posted?

Tags: feature-request, subjective-questions, questions, flagging, reputation

I am observing some of the users are asking questions on SQA Stack exchange platform, in a way that its customer support for IT industry. I am really feel un-happy for those who are having power and expected to use it in a correct and importantly proper manner.[As defined by stack platform]

Users are keep posting all the classes and whole code in a question? We have provision to Hold/Close the question asked. But I have mainly two questions:

1. Can we restrict/review the question before getting posted?
2. If above situation is continuous driven by specific user can we vote against those user? [ May be in terms of restricting few days or reducing reputation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been absent for a few days now with a family vacation, so I'm sorry some of those haven't been cleaned up yet.

First, yes there are actions the moderation team can take to prevent users from asking questions, but we tend to do it only in extreme cases. I don't believe there is an option to let them post but have it reviewed first. If there is, I've never seen it.

But the best thing we can do is to educate. When voting to close, don't just close. If someone hasn't posted a comment that says why they're voting to close, the person is never going to know that what they're doing is wrong. It might be tedious, but it's the best way to get them to stop.